# How can I get transparency in beamer compiling with LaTeX in DVI mode?

Tags: beamer, transparency, dvi-mode

This is a follow-up question to [How to make partially transparent beamercolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55596/how-to-make-partially-transparent-beamercolorbox/55685#comment155437_55685)

I compiled the code in the answer from Gonzalo Medina, and I noticed the transparency only works with pdflatex.

Is there a way to get transparency with latex and dvipdf?

In my talk I have a lot of eps pictures and I wouldn't like to have to convert them to png.

Comment: Have you considered converting your [EPS to PDF](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: TeXLive does this automagically now.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I use neither TeXLive nor EPS graphics. My comment was more a suggestion than a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seriously doubt that you will get transparency with dvipdf (which uses dvips), as PostScript has no real concept of [transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Transparency).

If you have a recent TeXLive (2010 or newer), [your eps will be converted automagically](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-790009.1.7).