# transparency of beamercolorbox and opaqueness of its text

Tags: beamer, transparency

this is a follow up question to [How to make partially transparent beamercolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55596/how-to-make-partially-transparent-beamercolorbox/55685#comment155437_55685)

The question is that I would like to have a transparent beamercolorbox, but a not transparent text. What should I do? I also do not like the darker line on the top of the beamercolorbox. I am also open to other possibilities.
the following is a minimal example of the offending slide:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\colorlet{color1}{PineGreen}

 \mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{lily}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercolor{alert}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{text1}{fg=color1!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{text2}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=color1!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{box1}{fg=black,bg=Dandelion}
\setbeamercolor{box2}{fg=black,bg=SeaGreen}
\setbeamercolor{box3}{fg=black,bg=Aquamarine}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \begin{flushright}
    \insertframetitle\par
  \end{flushright}
}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{figures/PNG/ripple.png}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries,shape=\itshape,family=  \rmfamily}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide title}
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.35}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.35}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box2}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{text2} \bf T1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \end{itemize}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box3}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{text2} \bf T2}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \end{itemize}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{columns}  
\begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box1}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item element
  \item element
  \end{itemize}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the way the color boxes are built, the only approach I have found for the moment is to redefine `\beamerboxesrounded`, as implemente in `beamerbaseboxes.sty` to use `\pgfsetfillopacity` with the desired value controlled with `\opacitylevel`; the code below shows this redefinition (lines with changes are signaled with `%NEW`):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\colorlet{color1}{PineGreen}

 \mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{lily}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercolor{alert}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{text1}{fg=color1!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{text2}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=color1!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{box1}{fg=black,bg=Dandelion}
\setbeamercolor{box2}{fg=black,bg=SeaGreen}
\setbeamercolor{box3}{fg=black,bg=Aquamarine}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \begin{flushright}
    \insertframetitle\par
  \end{flushright}
}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{b}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large,series=\bfseries,shape=\itshape,family=  \rmfamily}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\opacitylevel{0.35}% change here the opacity level

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamerboxesrounded[2][]{%
  \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax%
  \vbox\bgroup%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{upper=block title,lower=block body,width=\textwidth,shadow=false}%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{#1}%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@lower}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{lower.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@upper}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{upper.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  %
  % Typeset head
  %
  \vskip4bp
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@upper}%
      #2%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{}%
    \ht\bmb@box=1.5pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=-4.5pt%
  \else%
    \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
    \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
    \ifdim\bmb@temp<1.5pt%
      \bmb@temp=1.5pt%
    \fi%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
    \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=\ht\bmb@box%
  \fi%
  \bmb@temp=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}
      \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
        \color{lower.bg}%
      \else%
        \color{upper.bg}%
      \fi%
      \pgfsetfillopacity{\opacitylevel}%NEW
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{-1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{3bp}{0bp}{3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-1bp}}%
      \bmb@dima=-\ht\bmb@box%
      \advance\bmb@dima by1pt%NEW
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \copy\bmb@box%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-1pt%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
  \else%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\bmb@width}{6pt}
      \bmb@dima=\bmb@width%
      \advance\bmb@dima by8bp%
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{-1bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{8bp}}
      \pgfusepath{clip}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{0bp}}\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@transition}}}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-0.5pt%
  \fi%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadow=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadow}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowball=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowball}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowballlarge}}%
  \fi%
  \setbox\bmb@colorbox=\hbox{{\pgfpicturetrue\pgfsetfillopacity{\opacitylevel}\pgfsetcolor{lower.bg}}}%NEW
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
    \vskip2pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@lower}%
    \colorlet{beamerstructure}{upper.bg}%
    \colorlet{structure}{upper.bg}%
    %\color{.}%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{slide title}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box2}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{text2} \bf T1}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \end{itemize}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box3}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{text2} \bf T2}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \item element
    \end{itemize}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{columns}  
\begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box1}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item element
  \item element
  \end{itemize}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `background` template I used the CTAN lion by Duane Bibby.

Comment: I tried to compile your code, but it hangs at: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty)) (./test4.out)
(./test4.out)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dictionary-En
glish.dict) (./test4.nav) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
<b.png, id=10, 351.3125pt x 312.16624pt> <use b.png> [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/ma
p/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./b.png (PNG copy)>])
*

Comment: @simona you have to use one of your own images instead of the placeholder `b`, so replace `b` in `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{b}`with the name (and path) of one of your actual images; seeing your initial code, I guess you should use `figures/PNG/ripple.png`.

Comment: yes, I used my own image. I also tried to remove the background image and it is hanging anyway

Comment: @simona Are you processing the exact code I posted? If not, please process the exact (i,e., with absolutely no change, except for the image file name). Do the error persists?

Comment: @simona any progress with the document or are you still having problems?

Comment: sorry, I was very busy with something. yes, it works

Comment: @simona No problem. Glad to hear it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tcolorbox` inner beamer theme. This allows you to replace the normal `beamercolorboxe`s with `tcolorboxes`, for which one can easily adjust the background opacity:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{text2}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{box2}{fg=black,bg=SeaGreen}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}}

\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\beamer@tcb@patchcolorbox
\makeatother
\tcbset{
  opacityback=0.6, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[shadow=false,rounded=true]{box2}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{text2} \bfseries Title}
    
    content
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]